# How do I split an array list into two array lists based on a delimiter?

Tags: java, arraylist

Suppose that I have an Array list of Array lists:

```
A = [2, 5, 6], [1, 6, 1], [], [7, 7], [4, 2], [9, 3]]
```

and I want to split them at the index where the element of the array list has the size of 0 so that it will look like this

```
x = [[2, 5, 6], [1, 6, 1]]
y = [[7, 7], [4, 2], [9, 3]]
```

but whenever I run my loop it comes out like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList temp= A.get(i);
    int size = temp.size();
    if(size != 0) {
       x.add(temp);
    }
       y.add(temp);
    }
```

```
x = [[2, 5, 6], [1, 6, 1], [7, 7], [4, 2], [9, 3]]
y = [[2, 5, 6], [1, 6, 1], [], [7, 7], [4, 2], [9, 3]]
```

Can anyone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Can you show how `x` and `y` are initialized?

Comment: @user7 i initialized them like this `ArrayList<ArrayList> x = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
ArrayList<ArrayList> y = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the destination array like this:

```
boolean addToX = true;

for(ArrayList temp : A) {
  if(temp.isEmpty()) {
    addToX = false;  
  } else if(addToX) {
    x.add(temp);
  } else {
    y.add(temp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You logic is off. Currently you are avoiding writing the empty list into `x`; other than that you always write to both `x` and `y`.

You can have a boolean to say which list the data must be written to. Once you see a list with size 0, switch the flag.

```
boolean writeToX = true;

for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList temp= A.get(i);
    int size = temp.size();
    if(size == 0) {
       writeToX = false;
       continue;
    }
    if (writeToX) {
        x.add(temp);
    } else {
        y.add(temp);
    }
      
}
```

Sidenote: Avoid using raw types.

[What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: Without `else` in the first check this will add the empty entry to the `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add a boolen flag to identify :-

```
    boolean flag=false;
    for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList temp= A.get(i);
        int size = temp.size();
        if(size != 0 && flag==false) {
           x.add(temp);
        }else if(size==0) {
           flag=true;
        }else if(size != 0 && flag==true){
            y.add(temp);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

it is normal because you are just not putting the empty element to x but you are putting all other elements to x and y. You can have a `boolean` parameter, such as `isNullArrayCome` and check it on every iteration. Here it is

```
boolean isNullArrayCome = false;
for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList temp= A.get(i);
    int size = temp.size();
    if(size == 0 ) {
      isNullArrayCome = true;
     }
     if(!isNullArrayCome){
       x.add(temp);
     } else {
       y.add(temp);
     }
}
```